# How do I include my php.ini file in my web app at Google Web Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How do I get the php.ini with my app on GAE?

I tried just putting it in the root, didn't help - also tried including it in the YAML file, that just gave me a mime error.

Please help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's placed in the root like with app.yaml from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini)

Now 2 things to keep in mind:

1. Some functions have been disabled in the App Engine implementation of PHP. Directives that target these functions will have no effect.
2. YAML is not php.ini syntax it's [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)

So if you are trying to change a config value of a directive that is not supported by GAEPHP than your change will not be visible.

May I ask what you are trying to modify?  Look [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Disabled_functions) for disabled functions that the directives will have no effect.

BTW if it's supported did you try restarting the server just in case?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm trying to set time session timeout time via php.ini :)

Comment: @user3227968 PHP sessions on AppEngine are very unreliable in their default form as they use memcache to store the session data, and so items get expired/flushed without any way to control when. To resolve this you will need to overwrite the session handler and insert a database layer to reliably persist the data.

Comment: @user3227968 See the warning on this page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Sessions

Comment: @IanGSY Exactly what you posted! Thanks. I didn't know the user was going to set sessions setting in the ini...

Comment: @user3227968 also if the answer satisfied you please mark the answer as valid (the check on the left top corner at the start of the answer)